# GridBagLayout elements not moving

Tags: java, swing, layout, layout-manager, gridbaglayout

I'm trying to move my buttons and label. I want the buttons down in the bottom right corner and the label right above them, but no matter how I change the layout system, they're all stuck on the same line and won't move at all.  How to get them to move?

```
        setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
        GridBagConstraints gc = new GridBagConstraints();

        gc.anchor = GridBagConstraints.CENTER;
        gc.weighty = 1;
        gc.gridx = 0;
        gc.gridy = 0;
        gc.ipadx = 5;
        pane.add(explain_lbl, gc);
        gc.ipadx = 1;
        gc.gridy = 1;
        gc.anchor = GridBagConstraints.PAGE_END; //bottom of space
        pane.add(btn_play_normal, gc);
        gc.ipadx = 6;
        gc.gridy = 1;;
        gc.anchor = GridBagConstraints.PAGE_END; //bottom of space

        gc.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
        gc.ipady = 0;       //reset to default
        gc.weighty = 1.0;   //request any extra vertical space
        gc.anchor = GridBagConstraints.PAGE_END; //bottom of space
        gc.insets = new Insets(10,0,0,0);  //top padding
        gc.gridx = 1;       //aligned with button 2
        gc.gridwidth = 2;   //2 columns wide
        gc.gridy = 2;       //third row
        pane.add(btn_play_ptr, gc);
```

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Comment: *"GridBagLayout elements not moving?"*  Adding a '?' to a statement does not make it a question.  I edited the question to add one.  Please [review the changes carefully](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/20568108/revisions) & if that is ***not*** your question, add one of your own!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are not setting the layout of `pane` the container that is accepting your GridBag components. You need to set **its** layout to GridBagLayout for the layout to work.

Specifically:

```
setLayout(new GridBagLayout());  // (A)

//  ....

pane.add(btn_play_normal, gc);  // (B)

// ...

pane.add(btn_play_ptr, gc);    // (C)
```

You're adding your components to pane using GridBagConstraints, gc, in (B) and (C), but you appear to be setting the layout of the `this` container (whatever it is) in (A), but not that of the `pane` container.

A solution: set pane's layout:

```
pane.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
```

Comment: @user2966573: sometimes all any of us need is just another set of eyes to look over our code, myself very much included. You're welcome.